# Selecting Names with Highest Aggregate in each Class

Tags: mysql, sql, groupwise-maximum

I'm new to SQL and I'm working with the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Student (
  StudentID int,
  Name nvarchar(30),
  Class nvarchar(30)
);

INSERT INTO Student (StudentID, Name, Class) 
VALUES (1,'Alfredo','X'), (2,'Jack','X'), (3,'Chris','Y'), (4,'Paul','Y');

CREATE TABLE Subject (
  SubjectID int,
  Name nvarchar(30),
  Class nvarchar(30)
);
INSERT INTO Subject (SubjectID, Name, Class)
VALUES (1,'Maths','X'), (2, 'Science','X'), (3, 'English','Y'), (4, 'Arts','Y');


CREATE TABLE Performance (
  StudentID int,
  SubjectID int,
  Marks int
);

INSERT INTO Performance (StudentID, SubjectID, Marks)
VALUES 
(1,1,61),(1,2,75),
(2,1,82),(2,2,64),
(3,3,82),(3,4,83),
(4,3,77),(4,4,81);
```

I'm trying to write a query to retrieve student names with the highest aggregate marks in each class.

My Expected Output is:

```
StudentID   Name    Marks   Class
2   Jack    146 X
3   Chris   165 Y
```

I tried using the following query to merge tables

```
SELECT * FROM Performance AS p

INNER JOIN
Student AS s
ON p.StudentId = s.StudentId
```

and this query to retrieve Aggregate Marks

```
SELECT StudentID, SUM(MARKS) FROM Performance GROUP BY StudentID
```

I'm quite clueless on how to merge these two queries to achieve my objective. Are there any other workarounds?

Please Advise

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: I'm using MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is how you can do it :

```
select * from 
(
select s.StudentID, name, class
  , sum(marks) Marks,row_number() over (partition by class order by sum(marks) desc) rn 
from Performance p
join Student s
 on s.StudentID = p.StudentID
group by StudentID ,name,class
) t
where rn = 1
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f53effe90b221fdee69900cd5c264d13)*